# Display array index in option box

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

I have an array of images which display one by one by click, and block of options in which user could choice what image to look. I want option to connect with array and display the number (or index) of current displaying image. Maybe you suggest me any method how I could do that. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
 var Image_array = [
        ["00.jpg", "1"],
        ["01.jpg", "2"],
        ["02.jpg", "3"],
        ["03.jpg", "4"],
        ["04.jpg", "5"],
        ["05.jpg", "6"],
        ["06.jpg", "7"]
      ]
function setf(thisv)
{
if (i == Image_array.length) i = 0;
rotatorbutton.src = Image_array[thisv][0];
}
var i = 0;
function right() {
 i++;
 if (i == Image_array.length) i = 0;
 rotatorbutton.src = Image_array[i][0];
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body >
<div onclick="right()">
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    document.write("<img id = 'rotatorbutton' src = '" + Image_array[0] + "' alt = ''/> ");
    </script>
</div>

<div class="pager">
    <form name="billy">
        <select name="option1" id="option" onchange="setf(this.selectedIndex)">
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                for (i = 0; i < Image_array.length; i++)
                {
                document.write("<option>" + Image_array[i][1]);
                }
            </script>
        </select>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            setf(0);
            </script>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, to be readable. And right off the top don't use `new Array()` use an array literal. For example the first one: `Image_array[0] = ["http://00.jpg", "1"];`

Comment: Sorry for the mess,  i reconstruct it - thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style></style>
    <script>
      var imageArray = [
        ["00.jpg", "1"],
        ["01.jpg", "2"],
        ["02.jpg", "3"],
        ["03.jpg", "4"],
        ["04.jpg", "5"],
        ["05.jpg", "6"],
        ["06.jpg", "7"]
      ]

      function addOptions(){
        var select = document.getElementById("select")
        for(var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; ++i){
          var option = document.createElement("option")
          option.innerHTML = imageArray[i][1]
          select.appendChild(option)
        }
      }

      function addRotation(){
        var select = document.getElementById("select")
        var image = document.getElementById("image")
        select.addEventListener("change", function(event){
          image.src = imageArray[this.selectedIndex][0]
        })
      }

      window.addEventListener("load", addOptions)
      window.addEventListener("load", addRotation)
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <img src="00.jpg" id="image">
      <select id="select">
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have found a few problems with your code.

- You shouldn't use document.write, because there are new and better ways to add content from the script, like using the Document object model.
- Like Edwin mentioned you shouldn't use "new Array()".
- Also like Edwin mentioned you should indent your code.
- In function "setf" you used "i" instead of "thisv".
- And you forget to close the tag "".

Above I give you a solution as an example.

Comment: Thanks! But how could i insert here onclick function - to change image by clicking on it, not by choice an option in select box? and how to display current image number when i change it by onclick function?

Comment: Okey, i`ll say another way - tell me please how to return the index of image which is current displayin from this part:

<div onclick="right()">
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
    document.write("<img id = 'rotatorbutton' src = '" + Image_array[0] + "' alt = ''/> ");
    </script>
</div>

Comment: You can do `parseInt(src, 10) - 1` that is going to give you the index. `src` is a property of the img element.